# Loading Values to Register in RISC-V

Tags: assembly, riscv

just wanted someone to help me with loading some values into certain registers.

The task was to "instruct the compiler to store the values of 0x2222333344445555 and 0x1111222233334444 at addresses 0x1000100010001000 and 0x1000100010001100 respectively. At run time load the values in the registers x6 and x7...".

From reading what the information provided from the PDF file as well as the question, so far my code looks like this:

```
ORG 0x1000100010001000
a: DD 0x2222333344445555

ORG 0x1000100010001100
b: DD 0x1111222233334444
```

Comment: Do RISC-V assemblers have pseudo-instructions like `la x6, a` or something that will expand to an instruction sequence to generate a static address in a register?  If so, use it then use a disassembler to see what you got.  Or even `ld x6, a` to construct a static address.  (e.g. using the low few bits of the address as part of an addressing mode instead of constructing the full address in a register first).  I forget RISC-V mnemonics for 8-byte load instructions; `ld` is the MIPS64 mnemonic.

Comment: which instruction set rv64i?

Comment: Yeah it should be rv64i. Well, we're using doublewords, not words so ld, sd instead of lw, sw, etc.

I'm also using the RISC-V Visual Simulator (RVS) since this is what my professor told us to use for the course. I'm sure there is a proper way to start the code than what I originally provided. For these questions, we were introduced stuff like DD, DM, ld, sd, ORG, if that helps. Really trying to learn this and trying to find good resources to help build my foundation for this course.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is rv64i, when asking risc-v questions like this you need to specify the instruction set.

you can start by letting a compiler guide you

```
void fun ( void )
{
    unsigned long long *a;
    a=0x1000100010001000;
    *a=0x2222333344445555;
    a=0x1000100010001100;
    *a=0x1111222233334444;
}
```

for example:

```
0000000000000000 <fun>:
   0:   10001737            lui x14,0x10001
   4:   02071793            slli    x15,x14,0x20
   8:   00000637            lui x12,0x0
   c:   97ba                    add x15,x15,x14
   e:   00063703            ld  x14,0(x12) # 0 <fun>
  12:   000006b7            lui x13,0x0
  16:   e398                    sd  x14,0(x15)
  18:   000007b7            lui x15,0x0
  1c:   0007b783            ld  x15,0(x15) # 0 <fun>
  20:   0006b703            ld  x14,0(x13) # 0 <fun>
  24:   e398                    sd  x14,0(x15)
  26:   8082                    ret

Disassembly of section .srodata.cst8:

0000000000000000 <.LC0>:
   0:   5555    
   2:   4444    
   4:   22223333

0000000000000008 <.LC1>:
   8:   1100    
   a:   1000    
   c:   1000    
   e:   1000    

0000000000000010 <.LC2>:
  10:   4444    
  12:   22223333
  16:   1111
```

Which shows both flavors of solution, building the value up in multiple instructions.  Or loading the value into the register.

Okay, yes, the compiler  used rv64ic, it was complaining about my command line so I used:

```
riscv64-none-elf-gcc -c -O2 so.c -o so.o
```

I built a cross compiler you can probably use godbolt if you prefer.

lui gives you 20 bits of immediate.  Using instructions only any 64 bit value would take 3 luis, some shifting and orring.  And an addi or orri.  Then use sd to do a double word (64 bit) store.

Comment: Woah woah, hold on, in your disassembly I see 4-byte instructions at not-4-byte-aligned addresses like 0xe and 0x12 caused by the insertion of a 2-byte instruction without padding. I thought according to the RISC-V specification 4-byte instructions are aligned to 4-byte boundaries? Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: I think it depends on the variation.  unaligned (at least on a halfword boundary) instructions are perfectly legal if the core accepts it.  the core I am most familiar with does.  Although rv32i I think does have some statement about alignment

Comment: but when you get into rv32ic adding the compressed instructions then would it make sense to require scattering nops around so the 32 bit instructions are aligned?  this is why the lower bits tell most of the story about the instruction,  so we can mix and match 16, 32 and 64 bit instructions...

Comment: I (you) would have to re-read the spec about when you include instructions other than rv32i, does the alignment rule then go away?  (fairly certain but would need to check the text again).  The person who wrote the core I am most familiar with is a contributor to the specs so I would think it conforms.   and gcc has no problem building unaligned...

Comment: I think they have to be 16 bit/halfword aligned

Comment: Apologies, the standard currently says that with the compressed instruction extension both 32-bit and 16-bit instructions require only alignment at 16-bit boundaries. Perhaps the material I read before was outdated.

Comment: Near the beginning of the RV32I section: "All are a fixed 32 bits in length and must be aligned on a four-byte boundary in memory."

Comment: "The alignment constraint for base ISA instructions is relaxed to a two-byte boundary when instruction extensions with 16-bit lengths or other odd multiples of 16-bit lengths are added (i.e., IALIGN=16)."

Comment: Yes, that is what I saw.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does have a pseudo instruction for direct loading of the registers called 'li' (load immediate).
The format is:
li  x5, 5    # load x2 register with 5 decimal.
The 'li' pseudo instruction uses 'addi' instruction combined with x0 register, which is always 0 (hardwired to 0). An example is:
addi x5, x0, 5 # this does exactly the same as the example above.
Instead of using gcc you can test your code here: https://riscvasm.lucasteske.dev/#